# If I am a leader of a squad in Star Wars Commander and I leave the squad what happens?

Tags: star-wars-commander

Who becomes the leader if I leave? 
I don't want to play this game any more but I don't want to leave my squad leaderless.

Comment: Can't you log in, make someone else the leader, and log out?

Comment: there is no such option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a recent [thread on swcommander.com](http://www.swcommander.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=163), you can't choose your successor. One will be assigned the role automatically:

> The squad member with the most medals inherits the leader role. I just did this last week and I had customer support confirm that's how it works before doing it

Comment: Didn't know that. Is there a remedy if the leader goes inactive? The only solution we found was to start a new alliance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I accidentally left the squad I started with my son this week (2/9/2015). I was in first place with medals, he was in third. When I left, he was automatically the new leader. When I rejoined, I went back to the top in medals, and he's in third,but is still the leader. I think it sets the new leader based on the order you joined.